# wpf Arabic text not displayed properly

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to display some Arabic text from Right to Left. So I set the flow direction as RightToLeft. Below is my program:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
    <TextBlock Margin="104,96,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="Auto" Text="(وقت القاعدة الرئيسية 1 (بتوقيت 12 ساعة"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="20" />
</Grid>
```

The output does not seem correct.The close parenthesis is appearing at a different position. the output is وقت القاعدة الرئيسية 1 (بتوقيت 12 ساعة)

Please give suggestions/solutions.

Comment: @user209293 what alternative to my approach are you looking for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that while your code 'looks' correct in XAML the first character is a '(' which isn't what you intend.  You intend for this to be the last character of a right-to-left string which means it should really be a ')' character (but in right-to-left languages its mirrored).

If you want your XAML to look right and WPF to display it correctly you need correct your brace and at a special unicode character &ux200F; marker character so that the XAML understands that the last ')' is still right-to-left.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bi-directional_text)

> In the algorithm, each sequence of
>   concatenated strong characters is
>   called a "run". A weak character that
>   is located between two strong
>   characters with the same orientation
>   will inherit their orientation. A weak
>   character that is located between two
>   strong characters with a different
>   writing direction, will inherit the
>   main context's writing direction (in
>   an LTR document the character will
>   become LTR, in an RTL document, it
>   will become RTL). If a "weak"
>   character is followed by another
>   "weak" character, the algorithm will
>   look at the first neighbouring
>   "strong" character. Sometimes this
>   leads to unintentional display errors.
>   These errors are corrected or
>   prevented with "pseudo-strong"
>   characters. Such Unicode control
>   characters are called marks. The mark
>   (U+200E ‎​ left-to-right mark (HTML:
>   ‎ ‎ LRM) or U+200F ‏​
>   right-to-left mark (HTML: ‏
>   ‏ RLM)) is to be inserted into a
>   location to make an enclosed weak
>   character inherit its writing
>   direction.

Try

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
    <TextBlock Margin="104,96,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="Auto" Text="وقت القاعدة الرئيسية 1 (بتوقيت 12 ساعة)‏"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="20" />
</Grid>
```

Note that while this looks the same, theres actually a hidden character and the ending parenthesis are different.

Comment: Is there any alternative approach?

Comment: Sorry, edited my answer, my previous code still gave the wrong answer.

Comment: I have changed the text block flow direction from LeftToRight and retained the Window Layout has RightToLeft. With this change it is displaying properly.

Comment: Try the last edit.  I tried to explain the problems with your string vs my string as theres no 'visual' difference.

Comment: @user209293 Added a quote from Wikipedia that explains better the problem of using text files with LTR and RTL text in the same file.